# Evaluate inequalities in formula string

Tags: php, math

How can I parse the string underneath:

```
"(x > y) * z"
// Should always return: 
// 1. float(0) if x < y
// 2. float(z) if x > y
```

I've tried to use **[EvalMath](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html)** like so:

```
$m = new EvalMath;
$m->evaluate("(4 > 1) * 5");
// Throws an error: "illegal character '>'"
```

I don't mind using an other class, or rewriting the formula. As long as I can return `z` when `x` is greater then `y` and elsewise `0` and as long as the formula stays a string.

Comment: Without going into details, we can't help

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @MarkBaker I did not want to go into details into why I can't use PHP variables because it's irrelevant to the question "how to use conditions in formula's".

Comment: @Asad: I've just editted my post, to more clearly show what's going on.

Comment: @Ambidex Does `EvalMath` support inequalities?

Comment: @Asad My bad... I did not actually run the code I've mentioned directly but indirectly, which returned a float(0) everytime it evaluated an error. 

It does indeed begin to look like I can't actually do this in EvalMath, is there any other way to parse a string with inequalities? I've edited my post with the corresponding error.

Comment: @Ambidex Well, all inequalities can be reduced to a subtraction that is either greater than or less than zero. So to check if `x > y`, you would evaluate `x - y`, then using standard PHP math check whether the result is positive, negative or zero. If `x - y` is positive, `x > y`. If it is zero, `x = y`. If it is negative, `x < y`.

Comment: @Asad As I would love to use a PHP math check, I simply can't. These formula's will be loaded dynamically. They are all formula's which calculate prices, and will sometimes have a much larger formula, or sometimes even tokens. This is just one of many. And till now, there is no way to know how to divide the string up in PHP checks.

Comment: @Ambidex For your purposes, wouldn't `max(0, x - y) * z` be equivalent to `(x > y) * z`? If so, you could replace all instances of `x > y` with `max(0, x - y)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22439/discussion-between-ambidex-and-asad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem boils down to re-expressing the inequality operators in terms of functions that EvalMath already supports. Since [this version](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/evalmath/evalmath.class.php) has `max` and `min` functions, we can re-express:

- `(x > y)` as

  ```
  min(1, max(0, (x - y)))
  ```
- `(x < y)` as

  ```
  min(1, max(0, (y - x)))
  ```

Note that this also covers exact equality, i.e. cases where x = y.

Comment: As already said in chat; Thanks a lot, this actually solves my original problem with evaluating a greater than condition in a formula string!

Comment: No worries, that was an interesting problem. :)

Comment: I have to add; while playing around today with this version of EvalMath, I noticed this is a heavily modified version and not totally independent. When triggering errors, it will throw errors on not being able to find the function get_string, which is a i18n (I think) function to throw the error strings.

Comment: You where talking about being able to solve exact equality too, but I don't see how that would be possible?

Comment: @Ambidex In the case where x = y, `x > y` returns 0, which is correct. Similarly, when x = y, `x < y` returns 0, which is also correct.